# Firebase Robo Test script does not record tapping a tappable textview?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-test-lab

[Robo Test Script image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EmKh.png)

"Log In" is tappable and it will direct the user to the log-in page. But when i tap on it, Robo Test script didn't record the action, although the page transition indeed happened on my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a customized handling of click events (which is usually the case with tappable TextViews), Robo script Recorder would not intercept the corresponding user action. You can add the missing action to the recorded Robo script manually following examples in [Robo scripts reference guide for clicks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-scripts-reference#click). You can identify the clicked element using some of its attributes, e.g., resource id or text.